# SQL Server best option for low-cost high-availability and queryable secondary?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, mirroring, high-availability, log-shipping

We have a heavily used database server (SQL 2012 Web edition) which is currently a single point of failure (nightly backups and no additional hardware provisioned!)

The server has a constant stream of data being added and periodic heavy-duty read operations to extract data for applications.

We're going to upgrade to SQL 2017 and then:

1) Split out the reads onto one server and the writes onto another

2) Have a better Disaster recovery situation - i.e. not have to wait a day to provision new hardware and restore backups. It's ok to lose a few minutes of data if we have to.

I've spent a while reading up on options and it seems the **Always On High Availability** groups are the best option.... however they require the Enterprise edition of SQL server (which for two 8 core servers is about ***20x*** more money than the "Server-5 CAL" option we need and just not justifiable!) - I'm aware there are also **Basic Availability Groups** with Standard edition, but they *don't support querying the secondaries*, which is no use to us.

**Log shipping** is not a bad option, except the fact that it either disconnects users or queues restores is a problem - we'll quite likely have users connected and they won't want to have their long-running queries terminated!

**Transactional replication** seems to be a bit too granular - table level, requiring tables to have primary keys etc. it feels like it's going to be a maintenance problem and not the appropriate solution

So, I'm left with **Database mirroring** - which Microsoft have *deprecated*! (although it's still there in SQL 2017, probably because there isn't a good, cheap alternative!)

I'd appreciate any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: How much latency is tolerable on the read side?

Comment: I wrote up an idea that at least partly resolves the problem you mention with Log Shipping : https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/sql-performance/readable-secondaries-on-a-budget

Comment: @TaraKizer - I'm going to say we need low latency on reads, although I think it's possible we could re-architect the read-side of things in the future so that's not so necessary.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - that's a neat idea, but "The reporting application uses the same information to determine at runtime what the connection string should be for the next report the user runs" is going to be a real pain for us as we have several applications and dynamic connections strings just feels dangerous for us...

Comment: @Mark Well I think I also went on to say you could make this transparent to the applications by just messing with DNS on every switch. You have 5 hostnames under the covers (`readonly1`, `readonly2`, etc.) and DNS at any one point is simply pointing `readonly` at whatever one is currently the active one (say, `readonly4`). The smarts don't have to be in the app or in SQL Server.

Comment: Low latency is a problem. Transactional replication is your best bet for Standard Edition. Otherwise, you are going to need to cough up the dough to use Availability Groups. Have you looked into RCSI though? You may not even need to split the workload. Enough hardware, tuned queries, good indexes and RCSI=often a happy environment.

Comment: There is an old saying, "You want it good, fast, and cheap? Okay, pick two." Sometimes there isn't a perfect solution if you have too many must-have requirements, and in those cases you often have to give up one or more needs. Just food for thought.

Comment: Have you discussed your usage with a Microsoft Licensing person?  I'm having trouble reconciling your "5-Cal license" with your description of usage.  And separating your reads may just not be something you can accomplish to sufficient transparency to your users at this stage.  But you can certainly improve your DR scenario timelines.

Comment: @JonathanFite - not talked to Microsoft yet- could be a good idea. The thing is that we get data streamed in via one connection and then use another connection to extract data into a form (no longer SQL Server) which can serve web applications which in turn have *many* users. This is why we don't actually need many CALs

Comment: @AaronBertrand well, good, fast and not requiring me to donate a kidney would do! :)

Comment: I don't see how you need that level of uptime for only 5 easily identified and licensed people ;)

Comment: @SeanGallardy-Microsoft not sure I understand you... the data is critical to the business so definitely need high availability and resilience. However there are not many "users" is it's basically a small number of applications which either trickle in data or hit the database (hard) for reads. But for the sake of argument, let's call it 10 cals then... we've not actually licensed the server yet - just investigating now... even with 10 cals, it's a good 10-15 times cheaper to go that way than the Enterprise route!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log shipping is what we end up using. However licensing dictates that we pay for additional licenses if we use the secondary in any way at all (even to take backups from)...